# Enable full screen mode in iBooks on iPhone

Tags: iphone, books

A recent iBooks update (1.5, I think) mentions a new "full screen reading mode" that gets rid of the junk on the top/bottom of the screen.

How do I actually get into this mode on the iPhone? I can't find an option for it in themes or font option.

Or is it only available on the iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official text of the feature says:

> Full-screen layout lets you focus on the words without distraction.

I believe that full screen feature is referring to only having the book title on top and the page number at the bottom of the screen. You can activate it by single tapping in the center of the book. This will get rid of all other UI elements, including the status bar on top.

It doesn't necessarily give you more screen real estate, it just gets rids of these extra distractions.

Here's a good example of the difference between "full screen" (left) and normal layout (right):

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't actually increase the reading area, it just hides the status bar and the additional UI elements, and actually **adds** the book title to the top.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, but contrary to my expectations, doesn't appear to actually allow more text on the screen at once. Just gets rid of the distracting junk at the top and bottom.

Answer (score 2):

What I have always done to get rid of the abstractions when reading a book is tap the screen.

In other words, with the book open, tap the book (page), briefly (and only once).